# Erro com expressão regular no PHP

Tags: php, regex

Alguém saberia me dizer por que razão essa expressão regular da erro no PHP?

```
/:[^\/\\]*/
```

Ela está sendo usada desta forma:

```
return '/' . preg_replace('/:[^\/\\]*/', '([^\/]*)', $value) . '/';
```

Estou tentando "quebrar" uma contra barra com outra porém o PHP se comporta como se estivesse quebrando o caractere "]" e me retorna o erro: "Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class".

Há outra forma de eu especificar uma contra barra literal em uma espressão regular do PHP?

Comment: Escape a barra invertida `/:[^\\/\\\\]*/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a expressão regular desta forma:

```
/:[^\/\\\\]*/
```

Referências:

- [Escape backslash [ \ ] in PHP regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369828/1608936)
- [Escape Sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Answer (score 3):

O que você quer fazer? Parece que quer dar parse em url. Se for, use o parse_url

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Caso nao seja, use o explode("/", $value)

Se for pra escapar, use o funções url

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.url.php

O uso de expressão regular no php pode ser substituído por vários outros métodos de melhor compreensão e funcionamento

Adicione exemplos do $value, e qual deveria ser a saida

Comment: Então, estou tentando criar uma expressão regular "mutante", eu pedo uma URL gero uma expressão regular com base nela para pegar ocorrências em outra, porém quando eu uso uma expressão regular e tento escapar uma contra barra não da certo (`'/[\\]/'`) o PHP interpreta como se eu estivesse quebrando o "]"...

Comment: Isso não resolve?

$value = "http:\/\/primeseven.com.br";
$replaced = stripcslashes($value);
var_dump($replaced);

Ainda não entendi, de exemplos da entrada, e da saida